# IIS8 URL Redirect with querystring

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

This rule doesn't add the querystring to the output and I can't work out why:-

```
<rule name="Show Week" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^show-week.aspx(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="showresort.aspx{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

The input URL is www.mysite.com/show-week.aspx?siteId=EUR&resortId=672&resortType=1&avail=0

The outupt URL should be www.mysite.com/showresort.aspx?siteId=EUR&resortId=672&resortType=1&avail=0

But what I get is just www.mysite.com/showresort.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trackAllCaptures to capture querystring and then append it to new URL.

```
<rule name="Show Week" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^show-week.aspx(.*)" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="showresort.aspx?{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Sorry, not working for me. Results the same. Other redirections work just fine as long as they don't have a querystring.

Comment: Enable Failed Request Tracing and see whats is going on...This is strange... http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Failed Request Tracing only logs under certain conditions and missing querystrings isn't one of them:(

Comment: check if appendquerystring is false.

Comment: That was it. In the confusion it was set "true" and added the querystring twice. Thanks. Appears to be working now with your code. Note, had to make a change to a line outside the rewriter to cause app to restart and take the change.